# Can Create Demiplane be used to expand or alter a demiplane created by Genesis?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, planes

Assuming a caster can get access to both spells, can they use a spell of the [Create Demiplane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-demiplane/) series to expand or modify the demiplane created by [Genesis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/genesis/)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why expand the already large demiplane created by Genesis? If my math is right, the result is similar to a create demiplate cast by a caster of over 1000th level (it is seriously much larger), or the equivalent to that number of re-casts of the spell.

Comment: @shadowkras mostly to modify. There is little use to stack 10' boxes on something that is a sphere 180' in radius (and growing). But for the sake of completness, its left there. The core of the question is to know if one spell can interfere with the other. And your math is right. The size additions to genesis are quadratic. In a few castings, you are adding land the size of California to your demiplane each casting. Lex Luthor would drool.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is actually in Create Demiplane. It says, in part -

> You can use this spell to expand a demiplane you created with create lesser demiplane

This is the rider from Create Demiplane, but the other spells in the series have the same basic text.

So, no, Create Demiplane will not affect a demiplane created with Genesis, or in fact, any other demiplane than one you yourself have created with a Create Demiplane spell.